# How to update a text file dynamically

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, web-server

I have Two Arduinos, One with the help of sensors it will dynamically updates in to my server database. Other Arduino, reads the stored contents from the server database and sends sms to phones.

Now, I have a text file in my server which updates dynamically for every 5 min - 10 min. I am trying to read that text file contents.

I want my server to be always connected, So It must be in `setup()` function.
I want update only to my text file which dynamically changes, so it must be `loop()` function.

How to implement this ? Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Does the content change via web interface or with a sensor/other function on the Arduino?

Comment: Is the Arduino the server or the client?

Comment: I have Two Arduinos, One with the help of sensors it will dynamically updates in to my server database. Other Arduino, reads the stored contents from the server database and sends sms to phones.

Comment: Is your server actually running on an Arduino?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield My server is separate. I am just using Arduino to submit the sensor information to my Server database and with other Arduino, I am sending sms to any phone number that request for the server data.

Comment: So which part do you need help with then?

Comment: I want the server connection in `setup()` and In `loop()` I want to updated only current content in the text file. How to update the `client.print("GET /current.txt");` dynamically in `loop()`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without details of how your server works.

If your arduino is simply connected to the server, the server could open the arduino serial port (e.g.: COM5: or /dev/ttyUSB0) and simply read data.  The arduino would only need to serialWrite() data for the server to parse and store.

If your arduino is not connected but has ethernet support you could do a HTTP request to your server, and pass the data as a parameters to the request, e.g.:

```
http://your.server.ip/send_data?param1=10.3&param2=5.6&param3=foo
```

When your server processes this HTTP request, it appends param1, param2, param3 to that text file.

The arduino could also beam data back to your server via IR, or bluetooth, etc.

There's lots of ways to do this.